# Verificar se dado já existe no banco com codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli, active-record

Estou iniciando com codeigniter usando a active record para fazer a conversa com o banco, e queria saber como faço para saber se um email já exite na db, teria que listar todos email e criar um foreache fazendo a verificação? Tem algum jeito mais simples?

Comment: Não, faça um consulta no banco especificando(`where`) o valor que deseja encontrar.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer com a biblioteca [form_validation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html). Você passa o nome do campo que deve ser único e o nome da tabela.

O `is_unique` irá validar isso.

```
is_unique[tbUsuario.campoEmail]
```

Fica assim

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('inputEmail', 'Email', 'required|valid_email|is_unique[tbUsuario.campoEmail]');
```

O `inputEmail` deve ser substituído pelo nome de seu input no HTML, depois o nome da tabela e o nome do campo no banco de dados. Adeque conforme seu modelo.

Depois executa a validação:

```
if(!$this->form_validation->run())
   ... fluxo de erro aqui
```

Answer (score 1):

Tente assim:

```
$this->load->database();
$query = $this->db->get_where('tabela',array('colunaemail'=>'email'));
$result = $query->result_array();
if(count($result) > 0) { //Existem } else { //não existe }
```

Veja o manual do CI:

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=get_where